# Issue with Double and Integer type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am facing an issue in checking the length of a card number but unable to deciper it as I am a newbie to vb.net. Please help me out

```
   dim C as Double
   C = CDbl(Val(InputBox("Kindly enter the card number", "Card Number")))
   if len(C) <> 15 then
   msgbox("something...")
   endif
```

Even after entering a 15 digit card number, it is entering the if condition.

Comment: Check the length of the string returned by InputBox() **before** you convert it to Double.

Comment: You must not convert to double but simply check the string length instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a string?

```
Dim C As String
C = InputBox("Kindly enter the card number", "Card Number")
If Len(C) <> 15 Then
    MsgBox("something...")
End If
```

Len() returns the number of bytes used by the variable C.

Double are using 64bit, in fact: Len(C) = 8

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0ycy938(v=vs.110).aspx